# Slurm quota does not change after job submission

Tags: slurm, quota

I have an account on a computer cluster with slurm. In theory, my account comes with a finite number of hours. However, it seems that computed hours are not taken into account by slurm.

I run

```
$squota
Account       Usage      Quota  Available
user-high     54      10000       9946
user-low      296529     600000     303471
```

Then run a job with script `run.slurm`

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=short
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1

time ./code_1.o
time ./code_2.o
```

execute the job

```
$sbatch run.slurm
```

The job completes succesfully:

```
$ cat slurm-xxxxx.out 

code_1 completed

real    74m42.620s
user    64m59.712s
sys 0m35.832s

code_2 completed 

real    92m37.033s
user    72m42.908s
sys 0m39.989s
```

and checked the quota after the job run

```
$squota
Account              Usage      Quota  Available
user-high              54      10000       9946
user-low      296529     600000     303471
```

Would it be correct to say that, from a practical standpoint, I have an infinite number of hours available?

Answer (score 0):

The `squota` command is not part of standard Slurm, so it is difficult to answer the question without knowing exactly how it works, but it could very well be that the information reported by this command has some delay compared to the reality. Run the command again one day after and see if it changes.

Also pay attention to the units ; I guess it is CPU.hour but if it's CPU.day, or Node.hour, then the job might have no noticeable effect on the quota.

Comment: Thanks, I have rerun the command weeks after the job run, and the units are CPU hours.